# how to change color according to different string in base adapter list view

Tags: android, string, listview, colors

> If the string equal to "Sell", the text color will be red.Otherwise if
>   "Buy", the color will be green. Here my code below.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_adv_item,parent,false);
        }

        Advertisement currAdv = advList.get(position);
        TextView date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_date);
        date.setText(currAdv.getmDate());
        date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_amount);
        name.setText(currAdv.getmAmount() + " at");

        TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
        price.setText(currAdv.getmPrice());

        TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_type);

        if (type.getText() == "Sell") {
            type.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            type.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        }

        type.setText(currAdv.getmType());


        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: so what is the problem in that?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (type.getText() == "Sell") {
```

to:

```
if (type.getText().equals("Sell")) {
```

otherwise you compare references and not strings

Comment: working but the list view mapping not correctly.Pls HELP

Comment: :-) - move type.setText(currAdv.getmType()); above if (type.getText().equals("Sell")) {

Comment: You should debug this to find a problem, I can only give you various hints, last one is to replace this if with: `if (currAdv.getmType().equalsIgnoreCase("Sell")) {`